# How do I print an image over multiple pages?

Tags: printing, pdf, image-processing

I have a very tall image (880x9445 pixels) which I would like to print (specifically, to PDF).

But when I print the image it always comes out as one page; there does not seem to be any way to scale its width to a page and thus end up with multiple pages.

I tried using the image viewer and GIMP, is there anything else that will give me this option?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use PosteRazor.

1. Start the Software Center.
2. Search for `PosteRazor`
3. Install it.

[image: Screenshot of PosteRazor]

PosteRazor allows to import an image and then takes you through a wizard that allows to cut it in pieces, depending on the type of paper you will be printing on.

Comment: Made for Ubuntu 6.06 still working perfectly in 2016.

Comment: This is also packaged in Debian.

Comment: "No Application Found"

Comment: This doesn't support large images.